# No sound on manjaro linux

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card, manjaro

The sound works fine on windows but not on manjaro. I have tried every possible configuration in pavu both on the "output devices" and "configuration tab". I had this problem on Artix linux aswell, so perhaps its an issue with "arch linux based distributions". How can I fix this? Is it a driver issue? How do I figure out my soundcard and where do I find its drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Since I was getting the audio from a DVI cable through my screen, I installed proprietary NVIDIA drivers and rebooted my system. The sound now works.